# Can I even use List<WebElement> in Selenium without getting StaleElementException?

Tags: java, selenium, staleelementreferenceexception

Similar questions were already asked a million times but I still haven't figured out the correct way how to solve this problem.

First question: Is it bad practice to iterate through a List of Webelements in Selenium?

I am a big fan of Lists in Java. Usually I find all the WebElements I am interested in and iterate over them. But if you do that then you often get a StaleElementException. I know what a StaleElementException is but I can't figure out the right way to prevent them while still using Lists.

What would you guys do in the following scenario:
I have a bunch of tiles in my webapp that I need to click and check whether the result is ok.
I would love to do something like this but it will often result in a StaleElementException:

```
List<WebElement> tiles = driver.findElements(By.className("box"));
for (WebElement tile: tiles) {
    //at this point I already get a stale element exception quite often.
    //How can I use Lists without getting a stale element at all?

    tile.click()
}
```

Is there a way to still use lists and never get a stale element? Can I re-find a element without using a "By" but by using an "old" WebElement?

Something like:

```
WebElement newWebElement = driver.findElement(oldWebElement)
```

Otherwise how would I even describe in my Code to find that one old WebElement from those dozen tiles I have since they don't have unique IDs?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?